# Is there any poker variant thats use more than five cards to form hands?

Tags: hand, poker-history, variant

While learning poker I stumbled upon [a site discussing "7 Card Poker Hands"](https://safeclub.com/poker/hands/7-card/) As well as discussing the well-known five card hands, it noted the existence of three card hands while denying that of seven card hands. The page did not explicitly mention which game uses three card hands and I was curious so I did some research and learned that [a variant named "Guts" uses it](https://wizardofodds.com/games/guts-poker/).

Well-known games such as Seven-card stud, Texas hold-em and Omaha hold-em all provide more than five cards at each players disposal but only the five that make the best hand count. Was there any initiative in the history of card games to create a hierarchy of hands involving more than five cards? Have they ever gained significant traction from the community?

In the case of seven cards, one may have came up with e.g.

- AAAA KKK - Big Full House
- AAA KKK Q - Two Three-of-a-kind
- A K Q 10 9 8 7 - Straight
- As Js 9s 8s 5s 4s 2s - Flush
- AAA KK QQ - Small Full House
- AA KK QQ J - Three Pair
- ...

Comment: Outside of table games, I am unaware of any variants that use more than 5 cards to make a hand. I'm sure they are out there, but I am unaware of any. I would imagine these are the type of things you might find in home games, etc. You could work out the hand rankings using poker probability and combinatorics. As I said I know of no variants so I also know of no rankings either. Interesting question though!

Comment: Search Cincinnati Poker.